# Isolate Excel VBA script to run aginst specific worksheets?

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet, password-protection

- I have an Excel spreadsheet that contains 7 worksheets.
- I need the **script below to be applied to only some of the worksheets** (*Sheet6* & *Sheet7*) whenever the document is saved.

I've spent several hours trying different modifications, must of which simply did not work.  The VBA debugger does not throw any errors, and when I test the script it never appears to run.

How can the script below be modified to run against specific worksheets, whenever I save the document from any of the worksheet tabs?

Thank you

---

### VBA - Lock Cells & Protect Sheet On Save

The script below will lock cells that contain values, and then password protect the sheet before saving.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim Cell As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        .Unprotect Password:=""
        .Cells.Locked = False
        For Each Cell In Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
            If Cell.Value = "" Then
                Cell.Locked = False
            Else
                Cell.Locked = True
            End If
        Next Cell
        .Protect Password:=""
         'Protect with blank password, you can change it
    End With
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

[Script Source](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=161591)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks to all of you skillful code examples!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `ActiveSheet` and use a `For Each` loop like so:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each sh In Array("Sheet1", "AnotherSheet", "OtherSheet")   
        With Sheets(sh)
            .Unprotect Password:=""
            .Cells.Locked = False
                For Each Cell In Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
                    If Cell.Value = "" Then
                        Cell.Locked = False
                    Else
                        Cell.Locked = True
                    End If
                Next
            .Protect Password:=""
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Using more than one sheet name within the   `For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CustomerList", "SiteNames")` is causing a **MS VB - Compile Error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.**  When I changed it to just one sheet for testing `For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CustomerList")` I don't get any errors, but it also does not lock the cells and protect the sheet.

Comment: +1 Thank you Macro Man!  Adding the Array resolved the error.  The script will now only be applied to the specified worksheet name, if one of the listed worksheets is active when saved.  This is an excellent solution!

Comment: Not a problem, don't forget to mark as the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you (you'll have messages to let you know when you are in the event and when it's started and over) :

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim Cell As Range
MsgBox "Event Workbook_BeforeSave Launched", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Started"

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

ReTry:
    With Sheet6
        .Unprotect Password:=""
        .Cells.Locked = False
        For Each Cell In .UsedRange
            If Cell.Value = "" Then
                Cell.Locked = False
            Else
                Cell.Locked = True
            End If
        Next Cell
        .Protect Password:=""
        'Protect with blank password, you can change it
    End With
    With Sheet7
        .Unprotect Password:=""
        .Cells.Locked = False
        For Each Cell In .UsedRange
            If Cell.Value = "" Then
                Cell.Locked = False
            Else
                Cell.Locked = True
            End If
        Next Cell
        .Protect Password:=""
        'Protect with blank password, you can change it
    End With

MsgBox "Event Workbook_BeforeSave Over", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Finished"
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " :" & vbCrLf & _
        Err.Description
    Resume ReTry

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code can be significantly shorted (run time wise) by

- Using `SpecialCells` rather than looping through each cell
- avoiding setting blank cells as being locked twice (minor compared to first point).

*updated*

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

For Each sh In Array("Sheet1", "AnotherSheet", "OtherSheet")
        With Sheets(sh)
            .Unprotect
            .Cells.Locked = True
                On Error Resume Next
                .Cells.SpecialCells(xlBlanks).Locked = False
                On Error GoTo 0
            .Protect
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```